# Using filters in cognitect-labs/aws-api

Tags: clojure

How to filter results with the library cognitect-labs/aws-api? I'd like, for instance, to filter ec2 instances by Tag Name or State..

I tried with

```
 (aws/invoke ec2 {:op :DescribeInstances :Filters [{:State ["available"]}]})
```

but it doesn't works

Regards
Matteo

Comment: Please edit your question to show: (1) what you tried, (2) what happened, and (3) what you want it to look like.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can see the documentation in a REPL (this is described in the [README](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api/)):

```
(require '[cognitect.aws.client.api :as aws])
(def ec2 (aws/client {:api :ec2}))
(aws/doc ec2 :DescribeInstances)

-------------------------
Request

{:Filters [:seq-of {:Name string, :Values [:seq-of string]}],
 :InstanceIds [:seq-of string],
 :DryRun boolean,
 :MaxResults integer,
 :NextToken string}
```

Also answered here: https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api/issues/152

Comment: Thanks". A real sample can be useful for others

   (aws/invoke ec2 {:op :DescribeInstances :request {:Filters [{:Name "tag:Name" :Values ["DQLKAAAA"]}]}})